# How do I open Google Maps App with loaded address onclick of TextView?

Tags: android, google-maps

I have a very simle TextView as shown below.

> ```
> <TextView
> android:layout_width="wrap_content"
> android:layout_height="wrap_content"
> android:text="Adress:"
> android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
> android:id="@+id/textView3"
> android:layout_alignTop="@+id/To" />
> ```
>
> Now this TextView will show an address and when the users clicks on the TextView I'd like it to open google maps app with the address loaded. Can anyone shed some light on this subject

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Common Intent on Android

https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-common.html

```
public void showMap(Uri geoLocation) {
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setData("geo:0,0?q=my+street+address"); //lat lng or address query
if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
    startActivity(intent);
}
```